# How do I join two tables in Big Query?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have two tables in Big Query

Table A:

```
+-------+---------+
| total |  date   | 
+-------+---------+
| 1     | 01-01-17| 
| 3     | 01-02-17| 
| 2     | 01-03-17| 
+-------+---------+
```

Table B:

```
+-------+---------+
| ..... |  date   | 
+-------+---------+
| .     | 01-01-17| 
| .     | 01-02-17| 
| .     | 01-03-17| 
| .     | 01-04-17| 
| .     | 01-05-17| 
+-------+---------+
```

I want to create a query where the results looks like the following table, where it includes all the date from Table B, and any total from Table A if it exists

```
+-------+---------+
| total |  date   | 
+-------+---------+
| 1     | 01-01-17| 
| 3     | 01-02-17| 
| 2     | 01-03-17| 
| NULL  | 01-04-17| 
| NULL  | 01-05-17| 
+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`left join`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left-outer-join):

```sql
SELECT    a.total, b."date"
FROM      b
LEFT JOIN a ON a."date" = b."date"
```

Comment: Just let me complete this answer by adding this documentation page about [optimizing join patterns in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns). You should know that JOIN patterns can be computationally expensive, and therefore you should optimize them, by following the guidelines presented in the documentation, such as performing broadcast joins first, or ordering the merged tables from larger to smaller.